# How can I add an element of one sublist to other?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have list.

```
st = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {}}
```

It is nessesary to add the first element of any sublist to start of other sublist. In a quick way. Example: from 1 to 2 sublist.

```
res = {{2, 3}, {1}, {}}
```

Maybe you have any ideas for such fucntion, which returns list after exchange?

```
func[{from_,to_},list_]:= ....
```

Comment: Cross-posting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735678/how-i-can-add-an-element-of-one-sublist-to-other - is rather discouraged on the Stack Exchange network of sites.  To be a good citizen you should really delete one of your versions of the question, probably the other one, this site is better for *Mathematica* questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
move[{from_, to_}, lst_] := ReplacePart[lst,
  {{from, 1} -> Nothing, {to} -> Prepend[lst[[from, 1]]][lst[[to]]]}]

move[{1, 2}, {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {}}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, {1}, {}}
> ```

Comment: It must be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {}};

move[a_][b_] :=
 MapAt[Nothing, {1, 1}] @ MapAt[{b[[1, 1]]} &, b, a]

move[2] @ list
```

{{2, 3}, {1}, {}}

```
move[3] @ list
```

{{2, 3}, {}, {1}}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SubsetMap` and `RotateLeft`:**

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {}};

moveFirst[k_List, from_Integer, to_Integer] := 
 SubsetMap[RotateLeft, 
   Insert[k, x, {to, 1}], {{1, from}, {to, 1}}] /. x -> Nothing
```

---

*Usage and results:*

```
moveFirst[list, 1, 2]
```

> {{2, 3}, {1}, {}}

```
moveFirst[list, 1, 3]
```

> {{2, 3}, {}, {1}}

Choose your x'es wisely.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceAt`:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {}};

move[{from_, to_}, lst_] := Module[{del, element},
del = Delete[lst, {from, 1}];
element = Extract[lst, {from, 1}];
ReplaceAt[del, x_ :> Append[x, element], {to}]]
```

*Usage and results*:

```
move[{1, 2}, list]

(*{{2, 3}, {1}, {}}*)

move[{1, 3}, list]

(*{{2, 3}, {}, {1}}*)
```